# If else statement not behaving as I think - Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

So I am trying to come up with a reliable method to determine if a user has o365 multi factor authentication configured on their account prior to a script running so They do not get re-enabled.

using:

```
$MFAUsers = Get-Msoluser -userprincipalname test.webjea@aus.com  | select "StrongAuthenticationRequirements"
```

outputs if they are enabled

```
StrongAuthenticationRequirements
--------------------------------
{Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement}
```

and the following if they are disabled

```
StrongAuthenticationRequirements
--------------------------------
{}
```

Ideally if the user is disabled then the script will run against their account enabling it.  If they are enabled then the script will skip them.
For testing I have this drawn up

```
if ($MFAUsers -eq "{Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement}") {
"NO MFA"
} 
Elseif ($MFAUsers -eq "{Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement}"){
"MFA"
}
```

When running this against the test account that has been enabled I still get the "no MFA" response

Anyone have any idea?  I'm sure it is something stupid but I really cant put my finger on it?  Is it seeing the "StrongAuthenticationRequirments" header?

Comment: The braces `{` and `}` indicate an array, they're not part of a string literal, which is what the code above is testing for. Try testing `$MFUsers.Length`.

Comment: Okay so I tried changing it to be
if ($MFAUsers.length -ne 63 )

Elseif ($MFAUsers.length -eq 63)

and i played with the values to include eq and ne 0 and i cant get it consistent.

Comment: The length property of an array is its element count. Strat with the basics: eamine the output of  `$MFUsers.GetType()` and `$MFUsers | gm`. You have to have some idea of the objects you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a multi-valued property, then this should work better:

```
if ($MFAUsers.Count -ne 0) {
```

Comment: so I tried this. and I can only seem to ever get it to say yes regardless of what that actual value of StrongAuthenticationRequirments.

I set it to be -ne 0 is yes and -eq 0 is no.

Comment: Perhaps `-ne $Null` will work better.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I can spot is that your if / elseif statement is doing the same thing.

Both are checking if "$MFAUsers" equals "{Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement}".

The correct operator for the if to check if "no MFA" would be:

```
if ($MFAUsers -ne "{Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement}") {
"NO MFA"
}
```

-ne for "not equals".

Secondly I would personally approach how your are gathering the data slightly differently if you are using powershell 3 or above.

```
$MFAUsers = (Get-Msoluser -userprincipalname test.webjea@aus.com).StrongAuthenticationRequirements

if ($MFAUsers -eq $null) {
    "NO MFA"
} 
Elseif ($MFAUsers -ne $null){
    "MFA"
}
```

If the property "StrongAuthenticationRequirements" does not return anything then this is a null value, it appears that the property result of "Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement" is an object from what I can see on Azure docs, this may not allow for a comparison to a literal string, unfortunately I do not have an MFA user on my tenancy to check this against.

Hopefully this helps.